# How can I set Icons with different size via API with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the size of a System.Drawing.Icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025401/selecting-the-size-of-a-system-drawing-icon)

I want set a different Icon for my application System.Drawing.Form depending on its state. There is the property Icon. The problem is that the Icon object has only one image size which is used for different sizes from the system.

Is there a solution with which I can set multiple Icons for a Form via API?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is more the inverse question.