# NotifyIcon icon looks terrible

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, windows-10

Using Windows Forms, I have a notification popup with the following code:

```
Notify.BalloonTipText = String.Format("Test 0", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3");                
Notify.Visible = true;
Notify.Icon = Properties.Resources.busy;
Notify.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None;
Notify.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
```

The resulting image looks terrible.

[image]

It doesn't seem to care that the icon has the correct dpi inside it.  It seems to always select the smallest and size it upwards, clearing the alpha channel to 0 at the same time.

I read about applications having to be DPI aware but I'm not sure how to do that with Windows Forms, or how to get it to load the most appropriate icon size.

Comment: That's not Windows that picks the clumsy icon size, [it is ResourceManager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4027068/17034).

Comment: Ok, I can select an icon myself but how do I find out which icon size it wants?

Comment: That's a completely different question, consider asking it.

Comment: "how to get it to load the most appropriate icon size" is in the question.