# Use biggest icon in the .ico file in a pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, ico

I have a windows form and I have an .ico file that contains the icon in 3 format: 16x16, 32x32, 48x48.
I want to show this icon on a form in a pictureBox. (Yes, in the form, not as the form or application icon!). But when I select the icon to be the Image property of the pictureBox, it appears with the smallest (16x16) format.
Is there a way to force somehow to 48x48 variant to appear?
Is this because the 1st image in the .ico file is shown in the pictureBox?

Comment: Why can't you use `png` or any other format?

Comment: I already have the .ico within the project, which is the application icon and the windows form icon. I don't see a point adding an extra resource, when it is already part of an existing resource.

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025401/selecting-the-size-of-a-system-drawing-icon

Comment: Thanks! I was able to manage it based on the other thread. So technically this is a duplicate...